# NLog different layout for different loggers

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

To fully use advantages of MDLC in NLog I'm trying to set MDLC params at the init method of all objects I need to identify later when debugging by logs.

For example, there is an `A` class with some `Foo()` method where I have something like `logger.Debug('Foo method started')`. There are some objects executing `Foo()` method async, so I have some MDLC params for this task, for example, `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("A_Id", this.id);`.

And there is an `B` class with some `Bar()` method which logs `logger.Debug('Bar method started')`. And again I need to identify `B` objects or just need some same params every log call, so I have `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("B_Id", this.id);`.

And there is no `Layout` properrty in `<Logger/>`. Only in `<Target/>`.
So I see 3 ways to include this MDLC params based on logger class:

1. Chaining `when` constructions:

   ```
   <variable name="optional" value="${aParams}${when:when=equals('${logger}','App.B'):inner=|${mdlc:item=B_id}}"/>

   <target layout="${optional}" 
   fileName="logs.txt"
   name="f"
   xsi:type="File"/>
   ```
2. To have multiple targets (one for each logger) and with the same fileName. Not sure it is really legal but as I remember I've seen that somewhere.

   ```
   <target layout="${mdlc:item=A_id}"
       fileName="logs.txt"
       name="f"
       xsi:type="File"/>

   <target layout="${mdlc:item=B_id}"
       fileName="logs.txt"
       name="f"
       xsi:type="File"/>
   ```
3. To have shared MDLC param like `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("Param", this.id);.` in `A` class and `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("Param", this.id);` in `B` class.

   ```
   <target layout="${mdlc:item=Param}"
       fileName="logs.txt"
       name="f"
       xsi:type="File"/>
   ```

The third one looks most easy to implement but if this is preferrable way I don't see any reasons to have dictionary and use only one key everywhere. So may be there is some easier way to do that or which is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is from a performance view the fastest, as NLog could print without checking the condition. Also the config is easier to read.

Option 2 is not supported.

Option 1 could be more flexible, but a bit slower.

NB: I'm not sure of the MDLC is best choice here. I think event properties is also an option.